# how to use preloader in buttonItem in dev extreme

Tags: devexpress, devextreme, devexpress-windows-ui

hello I am new to dev extreme
i have used extreme dev form but I am not able to preLoader spinner in the button item I have tried this code but nothing works for me

```
 <Form colCount={0} id="form" formData={employee} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       
      <SimpleItem dataField="Email" editorType="dxTextBox">
                <RequiredRule message="Email is required" />
                <EmailRule message="Email is invalid" />
               
      </SimpleItem>
       <SimpleItem dataField="Email" editorType="dxTextBox">
                <RequiredRule message="Email is required" />
                <EmailRule message="Email is invalid" />
               
              </SimpleItem>
     <ButtonItem horizontalAlignment="left" render={Btns}
              buttonOptions={buttonOptions} 
            />
      <Item>
         
        <Button id="button" width={'100%'} height={64}  onClick={handleLogin}>
          <div className="spinner">
           {loader && <BeatLoader color="#ffffff" />}
            <span className="dx-button-text">Login</span>
          </div>
        </Button>
      </Item>
    
    </Form>
```

and if I am using the button of dev extreme it's working I want you to use preloader in the dev extreme button item